# is there a proper way to replace the value in dataframe with another in efficient way?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Following is the example of the dataframe iam working with. here iam traying to replace the ED values with the homezip.

```
EmpZipCode         homeZip          
839E2              839E2
ED                 A83C3
ED                 938B4
ED                 B82E2
893D9              893D9
```

Here iam trying to replace unk value with homezip in a way that it takes off the first
alphabet if present else keeps all the value. Desired is as below:

```
EmpZipCode         homeZip          
839E2              839E2
83C3               A83C3
938B4              938B4
82E2               B82E2
893D9              893D9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need two `np.where` here , the 1st one is remove the alpha of the home zip, the 2nd one is replace the ED with previous output

```
s = np.where(df.homeZip.str[0].str.isalpha(),df.homeZip.str[1:], df.homeZip)
df['EmpZipCode'] = np.where(df['EmpZipCode'].eq('ED'), s , df.EmpZipCode)
df
Out[23]: 
  EmpZipCode homeZip
0      839E2   839E2
1       83C3   A83C3
2      938B4   938B4
3       82E2   B82E2
4      893D9   893D9
```

Comment: @gannu first we do the adjust in homezip if it is first letter alpha, we remove it , then when have the pre-clear fill value, just need to assign when it is ED